# How do I unit test my controller, which uses forms in it?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test below code with jasmine. I am not sure how to fake/pass angular forms to the login function. Any help/pointer in the right direction will be very helpful.

Regards,
Sameer

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = {};

    $scope.register = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.createUser({
          name: $scope.user.name,
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        })
        .then( function() {
          // Account created, redirect to home
          $location.path('/');
        })
        .catch( function(err) {
          err = err.data;
          $scope.errors = {};

          // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
          angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
            form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
            $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: `var form = {$valid: true};`?

Comment: but what about form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);

Comment: `form.theField = { $setValidity: function() {} };`

Comment: let me try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're using Jasmine, consider:
`jasmine.createSpyObj('theField', ['$setValidity']);`

Answer (score 0):

It's good to remember that this is the commented solution is okay because you should not need to whether $setValidity() is working. you should want to isolate to test that your controller does what ever it is supposed to do when that function is fired, or returning a certain value.  JB Nizet should probably move his comment to an answer.